# How to setup environment for BlackBerry 10 in-app payment tests?

Tags: in-app-purchase, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I would like to integrate the [Blackberry Payment Api](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.payment.html) on a Blackberry 10 app. Is it possible to test the api without a real device? The documentation is not explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to test the BlackBerry Payment API at the moment.

> Unfortunately there isn't really any exact way to test that functionality. Even for sandbox mode apps, as far as I know, checkExisting won't work as expected for purchased goods/subscriptions (since in this environment purchases are not charged).

[- @scdowny from Blackberry](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Framework/issues/638#issuecomment-14730161)

There are a few things I've done to test the BlackBerry Payment API...

1. set blackberry.payment.developmentMode = true

   - This will give you a couple devmode options to simulate reponses from BlackBerry's payment service.
2. Stub out blackberry.payment to suit your various use cases... it's error prone but what I've had to resort to. [Here's an example from my app using Sinon.](https://github.com/achan/snooby/blob/master/tests/spec/SupportSpec.js#L71)

Comment: Does blackberry.payment.developmentMode = true works on the simulator or do I need the real device?

Comment: I don't have time to go through this in detail yet, but this devblog post may shed some light on the issue: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/01/blackberry-payment-services-sandbox/